# School timetable

Tags: software-recommendation, project-management

I am using Linux, specifically Ubuntu 14.04. I am a high school teacher and I want a software to create a school timetable. I want to just to feed it with the class lessons and teacher, for the teacher section, I want to just provide it with subjects being taught by the teacher, after that I want it to auto generate it. In Windows I saw aSc timetable,but what can i have for Linux.

Comment: [FET](http://lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/) maybe? You can install it with `sudo apt-get install fet`

Comment: Great suggestion, I have installed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Fet timetable](http://lalescu.ro/liviu/fet/)

Has a lot of features and a bit complicated to use, but once you get the hang of it it, it's pretty good.

Hope this helps, Cheers.